# Not able to mock the database Django chain queries

Tags: python-3.x, django-models, mocking, python-unittest

I am trying to mock the django chain queries. These are

```
 1. MyModel.objects.filter(userId=userId).exists()
 2. mrvDb = MyModel.objects.filter(userId=userId).order_by('-dateViewed')
```

.

I am trying to mock the Query 1. Below is my approach approach

```
   @mock.patch('myapp.models.MyModel.objects')
   @mock.patch('myapp.models.MyModel.objects')
   def test_retrieveMRVListService(self, param, most_Recently_Viewed_List):

      mock_MRVList_data = mock.MagicMock(spec=MyModel)
      mock_MRVList_data.userId = 6
      mock_MRVList_data.policyId = 6
      most_Recently_Viewed_List.filter.return_value = [mock_MRVList_data]  

    # param.filter.return_value = param
    param.filter.exists.return_value = "True"
```

For this. I am getting  error: (AttributeError: 'list' 
     object has no attribute 'exists')

I am trying to test this method.

```
def retrieveMRVListService(userId):
    if mostRecentlyViewedList.objects.filter(userId=userId).exists():
        mrvDb = mostRecentlyViewedList.objects.filter(
            userId=userId
            ).order_by('-dateViewed')[:5]
        mrvList = []
        for mrv in mrvDb:
            mrvData = {}
            mrvData["userId"] = mrv.userId
            mrvData["policyId"] = mrv.policyId
            mrvList.append(mrvData)
    else:
        mrvList = []
    return mrvList
```

I am newbie in unittest and mock/test django queries. Can anyone help to solve the chain queries. Any help or lead, I will really appreciate.
Please let me know if any information required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have done most of the work already, which is actually amazing as most people in Python don't even know how to use a Mock. What is actually tripping you up is that the `most_Recently_Viewed_List.filter.return_value` is actually a `List`, and it correctly says it does not have the "exists" attribute (because it doesn't).

So breaking it down by steps:

1. MyModel.objects.filter(userId=userId) returns a `QuerySet` object.
2. Then you call `exists()` on the QuerySet that was returned on step 1.

So when you patch/mock an object you have to keep proper track of what is actually being called and where.

What you could do instead is return a different Mock in step 1 and then modify the return calls of that object as if it were that original `QuerySet`:

```
mock_queryset = Mock() # Create a mock of the QuerySet

# in Django calling filter() returns a QuerySet, so lets do that

most_Recently_Viewed_List.filter.return_value = mock_queryset

# now modify the return value for the calls you make on that queryset
mock_queryset.exists.return_value = True
mock_queryset.order_by.return_value = [mock_MRVList_data] # just like your original code
```

As you can see what we're actually doing now is mocking the actual thing you were calling in your code.

Comment: Hey @William Bright  if I have to again only mock query **MyModel.objects.filter(userId=userId)** after the query no 1 and 2 that I have mentioned in the above problem. How to mock it again in the same method.
coz if i am mocking it like **mock_queryset.filter.return_value = [mock_MRVList_data]**. It is not working. Correct me here.

Comment: @Learner i'd look up something like a "side effect" where you can essentially provide a number of things that you would like to be returned